# How do I detect the audio left/right balance?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I'm trying to detect the audio left/right balance programmatically, and there doesn't seem to be an api for getting the value of this setting. I was able to find the `UIAccessibilityIsMonoAudioEnabled()` method for detecting if the user has enabled mono audio, but I can't find an equivalent function for the audio balance.

Anyone know how I can do this?

P.S. Go to Settings->General->Accessibility and then scroll down to "Hearing" to set these options

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that you want a numerical representation of the output for the audio levels from an app?

Comment: A numerical representation of the balance between the left right channels would be ideal, but a boolean isBalanceCentered? value would work as well.

Comment: I wrote an app recently that shows the balance from the mic or a specific file being played within the app, haven't however done something that monitors the general phone output. If that would help you I can put it in an answer.

Comment: I want to be able to monitor the balance of the headphone output. I want to know that if I send the same amplitude signal to the headphone jack on the left and right channels, they will actually be sent out at the same amplitude. I don't think this is the same as what you're measuring. Also, the mic input is mono isn't it? Not sure what you're measuring there.

Comment: @MikeAkers found any solution yet? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I'm pretty sure that this is not an acceptable answer, but...*

After browsing through the various API's I think my conclusion is: **Not possible**.

There is no direct API that reads that specific setting. There is also no way of reading the value directly - as it is stored outside of your application sandbox.

My best suggestion is to file a feature request at [Apples Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem).

Comment: Yep, I've filed a radar, talked to Apple's audio engineers directly at WWDC and then filed a second radar :) Me posting this bounty is the last resort before we give up and try to find some other solution.

Comment: I think the reasonability for the lack of ability to read this value is because your not suppose to counter it - as the hearing aided probably has the balance tilted because they need it.

Comment: This is the reasoning I got from Apple as well and I can understand their position. A function like BOOL audioBalanceIsCentered() would meet my needs and not lead to abuse, but even this doesn't exist.

Comment: Reasoning was the word I was looking for! :)
But I agree. A simple boolean would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but this looked as though it may help.

```
struct AudioBalanceFade {
    Float32                   mLeftRightBalance;
    Float32                   mBackFrontFade;
    UInt32                    mType;
    const AudioChannelLayout  *mChannelLayout;
};
typedef struct AudioBalanceFade AudioBalanceFade;
```

[Documentation (link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioFormatServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

or

```
- (float)peakPowerForChannel:(NSUInteger)channelNumber
```

Comment: peakPowerForChannel is used for metering the input, not the output... so that probably doesn't help us. I'll take a look at AudioBalanceFade, but at first glance it appears to be more related to getting properties of a recorded audio file, not the audio outputs.